# Identifying rows in data.frames based on complex rules

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

In two previous questions I have asked how to identify and extract substrings based on complex rules:

- [Identifying substrings based on complex rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449589/identifying-substrings-based-on-complex-rules)
- [Extracting capturing groups from a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843488/extracting-capturing-groups-from-a-regex)

The current question concerns how you would achieve the same end in a `data.frame` structure. Let's say you have a `data.frame` as follows:

```
data.frame(time = seq(1:10), 
event = c("FA", "EX", "I1", "FA", "FA", "I3", "EX", "EX", "EX", "I3"), 
actor = c("John", "Alex", "John", "Alex", "Tim", "Sandra", "Sara", "John", "Eliza", "Alex"))

time event actor
1    FA    John
2    EX    Alex
3    I1    John
4    FA    Alex
5    FA    Tim
6    I3    Sandra
7    EX    Sara
8    EX    John
9    EX    Eliza
10   I3    Alex
```

Now I want to move from time 1 to 10 and group all rows that precedes an I3. This means that I want to return a list of two data.frames (rows 1-6 and rows 7-10 should each form a separate data.frame to be placed in a common list). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @MrFlick: a list of data.frames. Thanks. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
split(dat, c(0, cumsum(dat$event=="I3"))[-(nrow(dat)+1)])

$`0`
  time event  actor
1    1    FA   John
2    2    EX   Alex
3    3    I1   John
4    4    FA   Alex
5    5    FA    Tim
6    6    I3 Sandra

$`1`
   time event actor
7     7    EX  Sara
8     8    EX  John
9     9    EX Eliza
10   10    I3  Alex
```

Answer (score 0):

That works too:

```
i3.index = which(data$event == "I3")
i3.start = c(1, i3.index[-length(i3.index)]+1)

indexMatrix = cbind(from = i3.start, end = i3.index)

apply(indexMatrix, 1, function(x){data[x[1]:x[2],]})

# [[1]]
# time event  actor
# 1    1    FA   John
# 2    2    EX   Alex
# 3    3    I1   John
# 4    4    FA   Alex
# 5    5    FA    Tim
# 6    6    I3 Sandra
# 
# [[2]]
# time event actor
# 7     7    EX  Sara
# 8     8    EX  John
# 9     9    EX Eliza
# 10   10    I3  Alex
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  arrange(time %>% desc) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(event == "I3")) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(group)
```